# Replace a specific dictionary entry

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

For my assignment I'm required to use file management in order to access information about the price/stock of certain items.

I'm currently using a dict like this

```
stock = {"Bread" : 27,
"Car" : 1,
"Banana" : 3000}
```

How would I go about to change the number of bananas in stock for instance?

Comment: Did you try searching for [this](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries)? `stock['Banana'] = new_value`

Comment: What does file management have to do with this? Are you reading from a file into a dictionary?

Comment: It would be hard to believe that your teacher(s) have not provided basic information about dictionaries, but just in case here is the [Python Tutorial section](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) on them.

Comment: @user161151 Correct, updating a dictionary is easy I'm just not sure how to do it to another file.

Comment: Ok. So presumably you know how to read the data from the file and store it into the `dict`. And your _real_ question is that you want to know how to write the modified data back to the file. So give it a try! It's not that hard. If you get stuck, put a [mcve] into your question and we'll help you fix it.

Comment: This is like the first thing you do with a dictionary after creating it. Read a tutorial.

Answer (score 2):

`stock["Banana"] = new_value` should do it.

Comment: While this does answer the _title_ of my question, I can't access a dictionary in another file with this.

Comment: @Carlgroth, it doesn't just answer the title. it answers the body as well. I see the comment you made, but it doesn't clarify what your problem is percisely. I suggest you try and ask the question you want answered exactly, instead of hoping we guess your problem. State your mission statement, and pseudo-code for what you want to accomplish.

Answer (score 1):

You can access value using key in dictionary , so you can go like this -

```
stock['Banana']=23  // any desired number
```